# NSMutableArray automatically typecasting into NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I created an NSMutableArray object by

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

and used method componentsSeperatedByString: as

```
array = [myString componentsSeperatedByString:@"++"];
```

but when I performed operation on array like,

```
[array removeAllObjects];
```

I got exception like "removeAllObjects unrecognized selector send to instance".

I solved this issue by modifying code like,

```
NSArray *components = [myString componentsSeperatedByString:@"++"];



array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:components];
```

and I after that could perform operation like

```
[array removeAllObjects];
```

My doubt is why did NSMutableArray automaticaqlly converted to NSArray? How Can I avoid automatic type conversion like this, to prevent exceptions? Thanks in advance....

Comment: Ninte oru doubt.. ..ho. Da doudt undel ennod chodeeru. nan parayam nan aaranennum nee arraennum..kettoda..Mundaykkal rakese..:))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a mistake in your understanding of how Objective-C works. This line:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

allocates and initializes the array, and the pointer `array` points to this object. Now, this line:

```
array = [myString componentsSeperatedByString:@"++"];
```

makes the `array` pointer to point to the new array returned by `componentsSeparatedByString` method. You loose the reference to your alloced and inited mutable array when you do this, and you create the memory leak if you don't use ARC.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because `[myString componentsSeperatedByString:@"++"]` returns an NSArray. You can try something like this:

```
array = [[myString componentsSeperatedByString:@"++"] mutableCopy];
```

or

```
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myString componentsSeperatedByString:@"++"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `– componentsSeparatedByString:` returns a `NSArray`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:

Do something like:

```
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myString componentsSeperatedByString:@"++"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

On the line

```
array = [myString componentsSeperatedByString:@"++"];
```

you are replacing the `NSMutableArray` you allocated with a new `NSArray` (and leaking your `NSMutableArray`.  Try using this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myString componentsSeperatedByString:@"++"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not converted, the array pointer could be UIButton* if you write something like

```
array = [self likeThatButton];
```

where likeThatButton is your method returning UIButton*. As always in objective c, NSMutableArray *array means only the Xcode will try to analyze your code and suggest convenient warnings and code completion.

Answer (score 0):

An NSMutableArray instance won't be converted automatically.

The method componentsSeperatedByString returns an NSArray-Object. You should get a compiler warning when assigning the return-value to a NSMutableArray-Pointer.